# Quantum machine learning and exponential compression

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, algorithms

There is a statement related to Quantum Machine Learning video lectures in which I get stuck. The explanation is derived from Seth Lloyd class.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lbndu5EIWvI

He starts defining a vector of data in complex space with dimension d (our vector data). Then He declares that at this vector space with d components is possible to associate d amplitudes of a quantum mechanical state. Therefore with this association we go from order d bits (to represent the classical component) to a n=log2(d )realising an exponential compression of the data. This is the most important statement in the class but I cannot grasp it. Am I missing something?

Comment: The argument is actually that if the classical data lives in $d=2^n$ bits, then it can be encoded in $n=\log_2(d)$ qubits. This is because the state space of $n$ qubits is $2^n$-dimensional and each classical bit gets encoded not in one qubit, but in (the probability amplitude associated with) one of $2^n$ basis states of $n$ qubits. The overall quantum state is then the superposition of (at most) $2^n$ basis states with amplitudes corresponding to the classical data.

Comment: According to my understanding, quantum machine learning may accelerate the training process of machine learning, but it does not seem to improve the performance of the machine learning.